# Does httpd need to run as root in ALL cases?

Tags: linux, apache, web

I just want to make sure my understanding is correct -

In *all* cases where it's desired for a website to be accessed through port 80, `httpd` *must* be run as root because otherwise it couldn't bind anything below port 1024?

I understand that it's poor practice to run the server itself as root.  Just wanted to be sure I understood the daemon part correctly.

Comment: This question might be a better fit for http://serverfault.com/. Yes, apache(HTTPD) run as root regardless you can set a specific user/group for each website along with the default user that will be used with the base of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Through [the use of Linux capabilities](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NonRootPortBinding) you can run httpd as a non-root user and still bind to ports lower than 1024. Note that doing this will allow *any* user to run httpd and bind to such a port, so do not do this on a non-secured system.

Comment: As side note: That's not the only reason it runs as root.

Comment: Ah.  Good to know.  So, if I leave httpd running as root on a production server, does that aspect in itself cause a security issue?  (Provided that the rest of the server is properly configured)

Comment: httpd drops root privileges by default if configured to run as another user once it has performed the actions it requires them for.